# Emberjs router multiple page app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ember.js

Is it possible to use ember for loading/updating models on different pages in an application?

I use asp.net MVC 4 application type and my urls are like this localhost/CustomItem   | localhost/Account/ViewPath   ...
Can I define models for each one and use ember to manipulate them? I am actually stuck on the Ember.Router.map. I have no idea how to define routes for each page.
Some of you may suggest use the default behavior of MVC but that is not suited for my needs.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET EmberJS Template?

Comment: I am using the default ember libraries in a wanna-be REST project.